# A Few Letter Equations

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

Here are 6 Letter Equations (6 LE). Can you guess what the letters stand for in these equations. The letters are the first letters to the word.

E.g. Question= 60 S in a M.     Answer= 60 seconds in a minute

1) 9 P of SA

2) 1600 PA

3) 54 C in A

4) 10 DS

> UPDATE: 5) 135 SS in R
>
> HINT for 5): ∞ R L to R

6) 32 B of L

*I am not sure what the most appropriate or correct tags would be for this sort of puzzle. Also, I'm not 100% certain that they are called letter equations.*

Comment: No. 2 is 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue for anyone who needs it. Can't get any of the rest

Comment: no. 5. is still unanswered.

Comment: I might have it now. If not could you give us a hint?

Comment: see update on 5 ... and note the (vague) theme

Comment: Ok I believe the theme to be places so now I need to work it out from there

Comment: Alright @LiamH, this time I got them all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I have finally got them all. Here they are:

1:

> 9 provinces of South Africa

2:

> 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue

3:

> 54 Countries in Africa

4:

> 10 Downing Street

5:

> 135 Spanish steps in Rome (credit Wu33o)

6:

> 32 Boroughs of London

Comment: This is not the correct answer I am looking for. It is certainly 54 C in A.

Comment: @LiamH okay I got one other anyway

Comment: No.1 is correct

Comment: These are all correct so far... Looks like i'll have to make my puzzles a lot harder in future!! I will leave this question open for now to see if you or others can get no.5.

Comment: no.5 . This isn't the answer I was looking for. I think there are more sovereign states than 135

Comment: Damn! Thought I had it there

Comment: I miss read no.3, I thought it was correct. You're very close! As for no.5, I will try and give another hint later on.

Comment: Thanks @LiamH assuming it must be afica not asia

Comment: No 5. is 135 Spanish Steps in Rome

Comment: Well, there's >1 W to S a C.

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: Thanks @LiamH, it was a good puzzle. Do some more like this in the future, there must be tons out there

Answer (score 6):

I think no. 3 is: (edited)

> 54 countries in Africa

The hint for no. 5 is:

> All roads lead to Rome

So the answer to the question is:

> 135 Spanish Steps in Rome

@Beastly Gerbil, feel free to add it to your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I have two of them.

3.

> 54 Countries in Africa

6.

> 32 Boroughs of London

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> 9 provinces of south africa
>  1600 philadelphia avenue (address of white house)
> 10 downing street
> 32 boroughs of london